# MySQL Query Optimization and joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, inner-join, bigdata

I am wondering whether my query should run faster, and whether I can make it run faster with query optimization. I have two tables, `tweets` and `nGrams` which contain about 600,000 and 13.8 million rows respectively. I am interested in joining them (`inner join`) however, for testing purposes, I only want 20 rows but I want to order them by a measure:

```
select
       tw.hash_tag, ng.nGram, COUNT(*) as cnt, 
from 
      tweets as tw
inner join 
      nGrams as ng on ng.tweet_id = tw.tweet_id
group by 
      tw.hash_tag, ng.nGram 
order by 
      cnt desc
limit 20
```

I do not have much experience with larger datasets; How long should this take? I think it should run faster than it is. If you need more information, please let me know. Also, try to include where I can find such information as I am not very experienced. I am using MySQL Workbench to run the query.

1. How can I make this query run faster?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: general rule for speeding things up: any field(s) used in a `where`, `group by`, `order by` or `join` clause should have an index on them.

Comment: You're querying and joining the entire set, then ordering by an aggregate value. There aren't many options to speeding that up. Do you have indexes on `tweets.tweet_id` and `ngrams.tweet_id`? And perhaps a MySQL guru could weigh in on if `COUNT(ng.tweet_id)` would be faster than `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: tweets.tweet_id is a primary key and ngrams.tweet_id is foreign key so they should both be indexed.

Comment: [MySQL - EXPLAIN <query>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). See the section **Obtaining Query Execution Plan Information**. This will get you pointed in the right direction.